# Restoring original image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I wanted to restore this image:

[image: Image link]

As you can see, image is has crumpled with yellowy colored waves (damaged by water). I'm unable to work with Photoshop or some kind of tools. But i can apply image-processing. What is the best way to restore this image.

Comment: What about manually replacing some color ranges? Or perhaps transform it to a grey-scale color?

Comment: I think this would be really hard to do properly, and certainly not a question suitable for SO. It's not only the color shifts, but also the shadows from the deformed paper. Consider flattening the paper by placing it inside a large book or similar for some time. Or try to create a very uniform omni-directional illumination to take the picture, such that there are no shadows and you can't see the paper deformations any more. As always, the solution is not in image processing, but proper imaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large top-hat filter on the intensity image, followed by a little contrast adjustment.

By means of per-channel gains, it should be possible to restore the paper color.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Can you share your filter, adjustment parameters? or code. Thank you.

Comment: This is a top-hat filter with an octogonal filter inscribed in a 13x13 square. Was made with a commercial software.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much. I've applied filter with this code [gist link](https://gist.github.com/lupino22/04ee4e2f257a0785d847fb636437c1f3). But i am really lost in color channels to restore paper color. Can you give me more information about restore paper color

Comment: @CyberprepNpl: apply independent gain/offset to the RGB channels and experiment

Comment: Finally i got almost same result as you. I was forgot to do the inverse for image after top-hat filter. Thank you so much.